# Remove datetime from filename created with strftime

Tags: python, regex, datetime

I have files with filenames such as:

```
"001_-_h_-_hydrogen.2014-09-13.14-27-45.jpg"
```

I would like to remove the datetime created with `strftime` from the filename and get:

```
"001_-_h_-_hydrogen.jpg"
```

The function would look like:

```
def remove_datetime(str): 

    return str_withoutdatetime
```

I'm really new to Regexes. How could I do that in Python?

Comment: Sorry I didn't express myself correctly. I meant remove the datetime from the filename string

Comment: From all the names, this was an example. The format though is gonna be "filename.Y-M-D.HH-MM-SS.jpg"

Comment: Considering the strings are always of the same format, you could probably just do: `lst = mystr.split('.'); mystr = lst[0] + '.' + lst[-1]`.  It would be a lot more efficient than Regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex of the form

```
(\.\d{2,4}(-\d{2}){2}){2}
```

Example usage

```
>>> str="001_-_h_-_hydrogen.2014-09-13.14-27-45.jpg"
>>> re.sub(r'(\.\d{2,4}(-\d{2}){2}){2}', '', str)
'001_-_h_-_hydrogen.jpg'
```

OR

to be more specific

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\.\d{2,4}(-\d{2}){2}){2}(?=.jpg)', '', str)
'001_-_h_-_hydrogen.jpg'
```

**What it does?**

- `\.` matches a `.` here it matches the dot after `hydrogen`
- `\d{2,4}` matches minimum of 2 (for hour) and maximum 4 (for year) digits
- `(-\d{2})` matches digits 2 times that is month and minute
- `{2}` quantifies two times, that is again it goes for a match for date/ or second
- `{2}` quantifies the match again for the entire tiem
- `(?=.jpg)` checks if the matched string is followed by `.jpg`

You can also write a less cryptic else long regex like

```
\.\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}\.\d{2}(-\d{2}){2}(?=.jpg)
```

which would do the same purpose as

```
>>> re.sub(r'.\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}\.\d{2}(-\d{2}){2}(?=.jpg)', '', str)
'001_-_h_-_hydrogen.jpg'
```

Comment: that is fancy... makes sense, but since the OP is "really new" to re, maybe you could break down how you are re-using repeated elements for him/her

Comment: @beroe I have added an explanation and straight forward method. Hope it make more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> x="001_-_h_-_hydrogen.2014-09-13.14-27-45.jpg"
>>> xnew= re.sub(r'\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}', '', x)
>>> xnew
'001_-_h_-_hydrogen.jpg'
```

See also: [Python re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)